# "Not much to it" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does "not much to it" adds to a sentence? Is it something like "it was nothing, there wasn't meaning to it" kind of thing?

Context: "Me and her hung out a few times shortly after mom passed away, but there wasn't much to it"

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is: to be much to something: there wasn't much to our relationship. Our relationship did not have anything important in it/to it.

To be a lot to something/to not be much to something [usually a relationship or experience or situation].

The hanging out is the something: to not be much to [our/their hanging out]. –